# Magick.NET Image Resize results in 0 byte file

Tags: c#, imagemagick, magick.net

I am trying to resize an image using Magick.NET, but after I call the `Resize` function the `FileSize` property reads `0`.  What am I doing wrong?

```
var image = new MagickImage(file.InputStream);
fileSize = image.FileSize; //will read something > 0
image.Resize(80, 80);
// image.FileSize will read 0
image.Write(stream); // results in a 0 byte stream
```

Comment: using the result of Resize() instead of the orig image?

Comment: @lboshuizen Resize is void.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like I was (mostly) wrong about the effects of `FileSize` reading `0` after calling `Resize`.  It does read `0`, but calling `Write` doesn't actually write nothing, it does populate the output stream as expected.  The real problem in my case came from code that followed this that consumed the contents of `stream` without resetting its `Location` back to `0`.